# Zend Framework PDF Page resize (scale) / rotate (page not an element)

Tags: zend-framework, merge, rotation, resize, zend-pdf

is there any possibility to resize an Zend_Pdf_Page Object from (e.g.) DIN-A4 to DIN-A6 (or any other size)?

i would like to merge 4 PDF (1 page) files to 1 pdf file (1 page). in each edge should be one of the 4 pdf files.

positioning, grid, e.g. is no problem... but how can i change the document size (of an existing pdf file) and how can i rotate the whole document?

i work with ZF1, but if the only way to fix this problem is to use an external library - no problem.

PS: sorry for my bad english (hope it is enough to understand my problem)

---

edit : 14:49 05/12/2014

also tried with imagick to convert pdf to image, but quality is too bad for printing as those small thumbs... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically your requirements could be done by transforming the page into a so called form XObject which can be place on a new created page. That's how FPDI works: http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/thumbnails/ (maybee an alternative for you).

I just checked the code of ZendPdf but I cannot find any method that may allow this.

Rotation can be done with FPDF/FPDI too: http://fpdf.org/en/script/script2.php

Answer (score 0):

In your code, if you have something like `$page = new Zend_Pdf_Page();` you can set here the desired dimensions.

For example, you can write `$page = new Zend_Pdf_Page('297:420');` for A6 format (if I'm not mistaken).

To represent an A4 page in landscape (wide) orientation, you can write 
`$page = new Zend_Pdf_Page('a4-landscape');` 
or 
 
`$page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4_LANDSCAPE);`

You can look at the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.pages.html#zend.pdf.pages.creation) or the source code of the constructor of the `Zend_Pdf_Page` class for more information.

I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: hey doydoy44, my problem is to resize an a4 document to an a6. Think you mean ceate a new one instead of resize an existing doc.

Comment: @NathanielR: In the source, I saw no way to resize a page (but maybe someone else will have the solution :) ). I was told that you had to merge can be used cloning method that call a new Zend_Pdf_Page(). :)

Comment: yeah damn... i think so too...  have searched google hours and hours. it´s a real damn problem,...  but i cant imagine that nobody has a solution for that prob... :)  i don't give up.